# SQL use comparison operator on aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregation

I am trying to get the `emp_id` of everyone who sold more than 100000.

This query returns all employees and their sales:

```
SELECT SUM(total_sales), emp_id 
FROM works_with
GROUP BY emp_id;
```

Something like this doesn't work:

```
SELECT emp_id 
FROM works_with
WHERE SUM(total_sales), emp_id
GROUP BY emp_id > 100000;
```

Do I need to use nested queries?

Comment: SQL parser cannot guess what you imply by `emp_id > 100000`. Just read this text directly and imagine yourself a DBMS: should it group by the evaluated condition (all `true` go to one group and all `false` go to another), should it group by `emp_id` and then select only those whose whose id is greater that 10000? How can it find that it needs to filter out summed `total_sales` if there were another aggregation function? "What if I we're a DBMS" is a good starting point to resolve a lot of the problems

Answer (score 3):

For this solution you need to group the data by `emp_id` and then with group by you need to use `having` clause instead of `where` clause to filter the data with following condition `SUM(total_sales)>100000`.

So with your first query is perfect. You just need to add     `having SUM(total_sales)>100000` with it.

```
SELECT emp_id 
FROM works_with 
GROUP BY emp_id 
having SUM(total_sales)>100000;
```